# Redirect a user after delete last product from cart in drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

I am using commerce in my drupal site.I need to redirect a user if he delete last item from cart. Any hook available for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rules module for that , in event remove item from cart check if shopping cart is empty if so redirect user

Comment: I am using ajax cart submit.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try below code to check if there is any product left in the cart when you delete product using AJAX. If this returns true you can redirect using jquery or javascript.

```
   $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
   $has_products = false;
   if($order && !empty($order->commerce_line_items)) {
          foreach ($order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $line_item_id) {
             $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id['line_item_id']);
          if($line_item->type == "product")
               $has_products = true;
    }
  }
  // If the cart is empty...
  if (!$order || !$has_products) {
```

Hope this helps...:)